# How to set Null to RecyclerView adapter In fragment

Tags: android, function, api, android-recyclerview, refresh

In my fragment RecyclerView is already showing some data when I run app. And Actually I want  when I refresh my data on some categories base I get null array if data is not exist on that particular categories. Now I want to set null to RecyclerView adapter so that it would refresh and display nothing due to null array.

Here is my Refreshing code function in fragment which is not working fine:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: fragment 2"+searchTxt);
                if(dataStoredArrayList!=null) {
                    dataStoredArrayList.clear();
                    myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                mparser = new SecondParseDataClass(context);
                mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                        if(dataSet!=null) {
                            dataStoredArrayList.addAll(dataSet);
                            myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        else{
                            dataStoredArrayList=null;
                            myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
                mparser.execute("http://192.168.3.10/testing.php", "2",searchTxt);

            }
        }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataStoredArrayList.clear()` instead of `dataStoredArrayList=null`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this adapter class which works perfectly

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import in.kpis.structure.R;


/**
 * Created by user on 6/21/2016.
 */
public class AdapterDemo extends BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<AdapterDemo.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//        private ImageView ivHorizontalImage;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
//            ivHorizontalImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivHorizontalImage);
        }
    }

    public void insertItemInList(String beanChat) {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(beanChat);
        notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
    }


    public void insertItemsInList(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        for (String beanChat : myList) {
            insertItemInList(beanChat);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }

    public void clearList() {
        if (list == null) return;
        list.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public AdapterDemo(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_nothing_to_display, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

and your code will be reduced to

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: fragment 2"+searchTxt);
                adapterDemo.clearList();
                mparser = new SecondParseDataClass(context);
                mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                        if(dataSet!=null) {
                            adapterDemo.insertItemsInList(dataSet);
                        }
                        else{
                            adapterDemo.clearList();
                        }
                    }
                });
                mparser.execute("http://192.168.3.10/testing.php", "2",searchTxt);

            }
        }, 0);
```

I insert items one by one, because it gives default animation effects with `recycler view`.